# Can I split an image to next page while displaying it on a pdf using fpdf library?

Tags: php, fpdf

I am writing a code in php 5 to generate a pdf file which will have the images.I am displaying full length images.The image gets cut as soon as it reaches the end of the page(i.e. bottom of the pdf page).I want the image to continue being displayed from the next page.So that the complete images is visible even if it is larger than the size of the pdf page.Is it possible?If so please help!!

Comment: I think it's a legitimate question--he doesn't know where to start and is asking whether it's even possible + a general direction. I'd be interested to know this myself even though I don't foresee having to do anything like this.

Comment: @suresh.g - I started with autopagebreak() but I was not aware that it is meant for text only.Basically, I want to make sure I am heading in the right direction before advancing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it can be done using fdpf alone. The `Image()` function does not support partial images; so you need to find a way to split the image beforehand (using *GD* or something similar.)

In short, you need to find out how much of the image to print per page (ie. how high is the printable area of the PDF page, excluding header, footer etc.), and then create a temporary image consisting of the correct clipping of the image. This is what you add with the `Image()` function.

If using GD, here is how to copy a portion of an image into another image:

[GD imagecopy() function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php)